# Excel Interop Worksheet copy raises exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm having a problem copying worksheets in Excel 2003 using Interop. The code works for 30-40 copies and then an exception is thrown "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC". The folowing test code already contains a patch as sugested in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684/en-us, but no success.
Does anyone know any workaround for this ?
Thanks in advance

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string template_path = @"c:\temp\template.xlt";
        string filename = @"c:\temp\testxl1.xls";
        if (File.Exists(filename))
            File.Delete(filename);

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo my_culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

        Excel.ApplicationClass xlapp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlapp.Visible = true;
        xlapp.UserControl = true;

        Excel.Workbook xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(template_path);

        xlwb.SaveAs(@filename,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);


        Excel.Worksheet xlws = xlwb.Worksheets["diario"] as Excel.Worksheet;

        int copies = 200;

        for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
        {
            #region Patch kb/210684

            if (copies % 10 == 0)
            {                    
                xlwb.Close(true, missing, missing);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlwb);
                xlwb = null;

                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlws);
                xlws = null;

                Application.DoEvents();

                xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(@filename, 0,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                xlws = xlwb.Worksheets["diario"] as Excel.Worksheet;

            }

            #endregion

            xlws.Copy(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, xlwb.Worksheets.Count);
        }

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlws);
        xlws = null;

        xlwb.Close(true, missing, missing);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlwb);
        xlwb = null;

        xlapp.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlapp);
        xlapp = null;

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = my_culture;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can find is that exception could be a Excel LCID issue when the local machine is not set to US English.

http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15

or

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369/en-us

Comment: Thanks, but that issue I already know. That's why  I use the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture workaround.